# I'm having some trouble with the .play function in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I have been trying to use audio in some new games I am making, and I have absolutely everything set up correctly, as it is a very easy program. The audio plays fine with the controls on, but I want to figure out how play it with Javascript, so a player event can trigger the sound.

I have tried:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>audio?</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <audio id='test'>
        <source src='test.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
        sorry
      </audio>
      <script>
        var myAudio=document.getElementsByName('test');
        myAudio.play();
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Again, a very simple code and the error message I am getting is:

> TypeError: myAudio.play is not a function.

Can anyone help with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should review [the documentation for `Document.getelementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName), as it seems you have two misunderstandings about its proper use:

1. The linked documentation points out that a successful call returns either a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) or an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object, both of which do not have any method `play()`. You seem to think that this method instead will return a single [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), which is not the case.
2. The linked documentation also makes light of the fact that it will target elements by their `name` attributes. You haven't used a `name` attribute in any of the elements you provided in your HTML - the `id` you seem to want to reference is absolutely ***not*** the same as a `name`.

   <sup>(This is only untrue for Internet Explorer 10 and below, where elements would be returned if *either* the `id` or `name` values matched the value of the parameter you pass. However, relying on this non-standard behavior isn't a great practice to take up, especially considering IE's dwindling market share.)</sup>

In this scenario, where you are confident there will only ever be one element with the ID of `test`, you may wish to instead use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead (which returns the `Node` you're seemingly looking for):

```
var myAudio=document.querySelector('#test');
myAudio.play();
```

Alternatively, [`Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) would also work in this scenario:

```
var myAudio=document.getElementById('test');
myAudio.play();
```

Comment: Oh my goodness I accidentally put getElementByName()!!!!! This is very embarrassing... I am so sorry but that does not work either. I tried getelementbyid first then switched to by name later

Comment: @Ov3r10rd Your comment does not provide any clarity as to what the actual issue is - can you please edit your original question to conform with the guidelines on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and making a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Right now, it's not clear whether you've used the `name` attribute in your HTML (your snippet does not reflect this), the `id` attribute in your HTML, or neither.